# Deploy ASPX page to Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I am working with Sharepoint site. For project I have given Site URL where I want to deploy my application. In this project I have folder Layouts. Inside this folder I have other folders. I have one Application Page Support.aspx inside one of this folder. Now the problem is, When I change something on Support.aspx.cs file and deploy it. I get message Deploy Succeeded. I can see my code change. But if I make any change in Support.aspx file and deply it. I can still see message Deploy Succeeded. But this change don't go through.

For Example, I put one checkbox in my Support.aspx file than deploy my project. I can not see this checkbox on page. How can I deploy my ASPX pages ?I even try to create Sharepoint Mapped Folder, But I didn't get luck on this.

Comment: Have you checked in sharepoint folder that deployed aspx page matches local? If it matches then please try to do iisreset.

Comment: Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets - Yes I check it with sharepoint folder. It is same as local. But when I check modification date for that file it didn't change. then I delete that file from Sharepoint folder and deploy it again. Now It get change. But everytime I need to delete file that I want to update.

Comment: How are you deploying asp page? Using sharepoint mapped folder or using module?